How to fix these errors in installing slither-analyzer in VSC? : LINK : fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe', Failed building wheel for lru-dict
I'm no coding wizard and have seen solutions but can't put together on how to do it.
For context:
I'm trying to just conduct a demonstration of me using VSC with slither-analyzer to batch scan for vulnerabilities in a dataset of smart contracts I'm planning to use for my practical of my essay.
The errors in questions in trying to install slither-analyzer are:
Building wheel for lru-dict (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]

LINK : fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.39.33519\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1158
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lru-dict
  Running setup.py clean for lru-dict
Failed to build lru-dict
ERROR: Could not build wheels for lru-dict, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

For the LNK1158 can't run "rc.exe." I've seen solutions of I think copy and pasting "rc.exe" into the Visual Studio Code directory but it looks different to mine and the PATH and ENV I can't find or just don't understand.
For the ERROR: Failed building wheel for lru-dict I have no clue.
